# How to get initial data using Spring RabbitMQ and websockets

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-websocket, spring-rabbit

we are using in our application websockets with combination RabbitMQ and I need solve following use-case:

User sing in into JS application, and application starts subscribing websocket topic for new messages.

Consider following situation:

User is offline and new messages comming from multiple sources (for instance messages m1, m2, m3). User isn't subscribing for these messages yet, so messages are only stored into database. In some point (time T) user sing-in into application and start subscribing, and messages m4, m5, m6 are received via websockets. User needs to know since when, or ID of last stored and not received message which is in this case m3. Or just simple send initial batch of messages when start subscribing. Do you have idea what is elegant way to solve this in spring?

This is my rabbitmq listener which handle message created by another microservice, and publish it to websocket channel which is subscribed by specific user.

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "${event.queue.message-created}")
public void handleMessageCreatedEvent(MessageCreatedEvent event) {
    simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/user/" + event.getUsername() + "/exchange/amq.direct/chat.message", event);
}
```

When new message arrived to websocket user will handle it. So I need know since when user is listening, or what is last message which which came and user didn't handle it and have to be fetched additionally via REST.

Comment: Looks like you simply should add a a logic by asking if this user is online and this user with messages stored in database are not delivered then queue them again.

Comment: I have a similar use case. What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 0):

In Sprint AMPQ, messages are persistent by default. But the queue in RabbitMQ needs to be persistent too. Otherwise, messages will not survive a restart of RabbitMQ.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-spring-amqp.html (see message persistence section)

> To have more control over the message persistence or over aspects of
> outbound messages, you need to use `RabbitTemplate#convertAndSend(...)`
> methods that accept a `MessagePostProcessor` parameter.
> `MessagePostProcessor` provides a callback before the message is
> actually sent, so this is a good place to modify the message payload
> or headers.

Now, this will help with client disconnect/reconnect, broker restart etc. But it won't help with any unexpected termination of the broker (RabbitMQ), like a power loss/crash as RabbitMQ doesn't do disk sync for every message as doing so would slow it down.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/semantics.html

> Overall the behaviour of the AMQP `tx` class, and more so its
> implementation on RabbitMQ, is closer to providing a `batching`
> feature than `ACID` capabilities known from the database world.

If you need absolute [ACID property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID), you need to change your design to include maybe a database back-end. In many messaging systems they are not preferred nor needed as `ACID` will slow things down and will require coordination between nodes in a cluster-type setup. [Read a similar discussion on Kafka and ACID](https://medium.com/@andrew_schofield/does-apache-kafka-do-acid-transactions-647b207f3d0e)

https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-spring-amqp.html (see message persistence section)

> Marking messages as persistent doesn't fully guarantee that a message
> won't be lost. Although it tells RabbitMQ to save the message to disk,
> there is still a short time window when RabbitMQ has accepted a
> message and hasn't saved it yet. Also, RabbitMQ doesn't do fsync(2)
> for every message -- it may be just saved to cache and not really
> written to the disk. The persistence guarantees aren't strong, but
> it's more than enough for our simple task queue. If you need a
> stronger guarantee then you can use publisher confirms.

As stated above, you can use [publisher confirms](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html) for a stronger guarantee of receipt (but still lacking ACID property)

See here for [RabbitMQ's reliability guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html) (all protocols not just AMQP)

See here for [AMQP queue types and properties](https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html) that may help understanding the nuances